# Can anybody explain "investor redemptions" in this context for me, please?

Tags: terminology

> As of late, hedge funds have had a rough time with some high-profile funds seeing large **investor redemptions**.

<sup>[CNBC: New York ripped for wasting money on hedge funds](http://www.cnbc.com/2016/10/17/new-york-ripped-for-wasting-money-on-hedge-funds.html)</sup>

Comment: I'd suggest googling for "redemption meaning in investment".

Comment: maybe that investors stopped supporting them I think redeem means taking back here.

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/redemption: See the meaning **EXCHANGE**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "redemption" is when *someone* makes a claim and takes *something* of value

> Redeem your coupon for 20% off the regular price.

An "investor redemption" is when an investor in a scheme reclaims their money back or withdrawals their investment.

Your passage is saying investors who have investments in hedge funds have been taking their money out of those funds.